# mvvmcross WPF How to add resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross

I'm having issues using mvvmcross by adding resource dictionary, see image.
I'm having the following error: An Error occured while finding the resource dioctionary.

[Error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1xFu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSDN:
Referenced Assembly Resource File
The pack URI for a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly uses the following authority and path:

Authority: application:///.

Path: The name of a resource file that is compiled into a referenced assembly.

Try this

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/LeagueOfAccount.Core;component/Themes/LolLoginTextBox.xaml"/>
```

see more [Pack URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)